# Information schema standard - where can I find more information?

Tags: information-schema, sql-standard

Wikipedia says that information schema is an ANSI-standard and I found many implementations of it but I can't find a paper by ANSI that describes it. Can you help me to find out more about it?

Comment: You can buy it directly from the [ANSI website](https://webstore.ansi.org/Standards/ISO/ISOIEC9075112016?source=blog&_ga=2.79304273.415731780.1622318132-1976051337.1622318132).

Comment: Hi, and welcome to dba.se! I think that this question is fair enough - it's about databases, standards and documentation - nuff said!

Comment: Hello, the book 'SQL in a nutshell' 3th edition (Kevin Kline) covers the schema standard in the first part of the book. Note that the book is outdated (sql-99, standard now is sql-2016) but my guess is there is not much changed for the schema.